# Speeding Up Query - Hangs at Sending Data - Indexed Correctly

Tags: mysql, index, primary-key, functions

I am looking for ways to speed up the below query. I currently have indices on `FIRST, LAST, UNIT_PARENT, HomeAddressLine1, HomeAddressLine2, HomeCityNAme, HomeStateAbbreviation, HomeZipCode, HomeZip4, and EMAIL` on the temp_1 table.

I also have indices on `first_name, last_name, unit_number, email_address, street_address_1, street_address_2, city, state, and postal_code` of the `temp_current_new_clients` tables.

Would it help to right the logic for the `Confidence_Code` variable in a function? Would that help my querying time?

Also, I currently do not have primary or foreign keys on the two tables in question. Would keys speed my query? Thank you.

```
SELECT
    a.PID AS PID,
    a.NID AS NID,
    a.UNIT_PARENT AS UNIT_PARENT,
    a.FIRST AS FIRST,
    a.MIDDLE AS MIDDLE,
    a.LAST AS LAST,
    a.HomeAddressLine1 AS HomeAddressLine1,
    a.HomeAddressLine2 AS HomeAddressLine2,
    a.HomeCityName AS HomeCityName,
    a.HomeStateAbbreviation AS HomeStateAbbreviation,
    a.HomeZipCode AS HomeZipCode,
    a.HomeZip4 AS HomeZip4,
    a.EMAIL AS EMAIL,
    a.Date_Log_Updated AS Date_Log_Updated,
    a.Log_Row_ID AS Log_Row_ID,
    b.personal_party_id AS Personal_Party_ID,
    8 * (LOWER(a.EMAIL) LIKE LOWER(b.email_address)) +
    (LOWER(a.HomeAddressLine1) SOUNDS LIKE LOWER(b.street_address_1)) +
    (LOWER(a.HomeAddressLine2) LIKE LOWER(b.street_address_2)) +
    (LOWER(a.HomeCityName) LIKE LOWER(b.city)) +
    (LOWER(a.HomeStateAbbreviation) LIKE LOWER(b.state)) +
    (LEFT(a.HomeZipCode,5) LIKE LEFT(b.postal_code,5)) +
    ((LOWER(a.FIRST) LIKE LOWER(b.first_name)) AND 
    (LOWER(a.LAST) LIKE LOWER(b.last_name)) AND 
    (a.UNIT_PARENT LIKE b.unit_number)) AS Confidence_Code,
    b.ingest_date AS Match_Date
FROM
    temp_1 AS a
INNER JOIN
    temp_current_new_clients AS b
ON
    a.FIRST = b.first_name
    AND a.LAST = b.last_name
    AND a.UNIT_PARENT = b.unit_number;
```

Comment: This this for SQL Server? Which version? And yes, you should put primary keys and foreign keys on the tables.

Comment: This is a MySQL server. I am performing a fuzzy match so by applying a first name, last name, unit number primary key would alter the logic of the fuzzy match because I want to calculate all confidence codes for a first name, last name, unit number match. Can I apply primary keys to either of the temp tables without disrupting the logic of the Confidence_Code?

Comment: String concatenation and matching is always going to perform slower than say an integer exact match. Are you actually using temp tables or just obscuring you actual table names on here?

Comment: I am creating these tables on the fly with the intention of dropping them later. This table is used for the next step in my stored procedure.